# [Android][CI/CD][pipelines] aapt2 W 09-29 11:28:13 896 896 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'

Tags: android, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I have tried to create pipelines for building my android app with android 13 (API level 33) on my gitlabs but I got an issue with that:

```
aapt2 W 09-29 11:28:13   896   896 LoadedArsc.cpp:682] Unknown chunk type '200'.
```

Error log:

```
----- End of the daemon log -----
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed)
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> Task :app:compileDevReleaseKotlin
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here is my pipelines config file:

```
image: openjdk:11-jdk

variables:
  ANDROID_COMPILE_SDK: "33"
  ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS: "33.0.0"
  ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS: "8512546"

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/

before_script:
  - apt-get --quiet update --yes
  - apt-get --quiet install --yes wget tar unzip lib32stdc++6 lib32z1

  - export ANDROID_HOME="${PWD}/android-home"
  - install -d $ANDROID_HOME
...

assembleDebug:
  interruptible: true
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

After researched and tried many ways to fix that, my solution is (for who got the same problem):

```
assembleDebug:
  stage: build
  script:
    - JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
    - ./gradlew --status
    - ./gradlew --stop
    - ./gradlew assembleDebug --no-daemon -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy="in-process"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug
```